# DB constantly exploding in Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models

I am trying to get going with django, which so far I have found to be amazing other than repeated db issues.

My latest is following the Django by Example book and I have followed everything to the letter, yet when following some simple instructions to add some data via the python shell api I get the following:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> from blog.models import Post
>>> user = User.objects.get(username='jamie')
>>> Post.objects.create(title='One More Post', slug='one-more-post', body='Post body', author='user')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jamie/dev/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 69, in handle
self.run_shell(shell=options['interface'])
  File "/Users/jamie/dev/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 61, in run_shell
raise ImportError
ImportError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/jamie/dev/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 127, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jamie/dev/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 346, in create
obj = self.model(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/jamie/dev/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 468, in __init__
setattr(self, field.name, rel_obj)
  File "/Users/jamie/dev/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 629, in __set__
self.field.rel.to._meta.object_name,
ValueError: Cannot assign "'user'": "Post.author" must be a "User" instance.
```

This has happened while following multiple tutorials and I am stumped. I followed standard instructions and installed, pip, python and django via terminal. Also using a virtual env so not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Your Post model expects a User instance (you are passing the literal string 'user' instead of the user instance variable)

Comment: Oh, that's embarrassing :) I fixed but am still getting Traceback errors for line 69 and line 61.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help - I just checked the errata of the book and the var post = is not declared.

Comment: Which Django version is this ? 1.9.13 ?  And on which OS are you working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead of your statement.

Use `user` variable instead of `'user'` string.

```
Post.objects.create(title='One More Post', slug='one-more-post',
                    body='Post body', author=user)
```